# OpenGL Ortho Coordinates

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I have an OpenGL view overlaid on top of an MKMapView.  My goal is to have the coordinates of the glView to have the same values of the MKMapPoints on the map.  To do this I found the values for the MKMapPoint on the top left and the bottom right of the map.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateTopLeft = [mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) toCoordinateFromView:mapView];
MKMapPoint pointTopLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinateTopLeft);

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateBottomRight = [mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(mapView.frame.size.width, mapView.frame.size.width) toCoordinateFromView:mapView];
MKMapPoint pointBottomRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinateBottomRight);
```

Then I set the right, left, bottom, and top coordinates of the glView to match these points accordingly.

```
glOrthof(pointTopLeft.x, pointBottomRight.x, pointBottomRight.y, pointTopLeft.y, -1, 1);
```

Unfortunately, this did not work.  The triangles that I tried to draw did not work.  I tested and the points that I was trying to draw **were** located in the correct domain.

Am I just misunderstanding how the glOrthof method works?

Comment: Not an answer to your question (hence the comment), but you're making an assumption that your coordinate system on the map view is evenly spaced, which isn't actually the case due to the curvature of the earth. This may not be a problem for some applications, but for those requiring high levels of accuracy it may well be.

Comment: MKMappoints are actually evenly spaced. They represent a point on a 2D projection of the map with parallel longitude lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried flipping pointBottomRight.y and pointTopLeft.y? The OpenGL y-coordinate system is inverted from most commonly used conventions.